# ValueError: time data 'Wed Jan 14 21:41:45 2015' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python

I am getting this error in python 3.4
I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

This is my code

```
print(time.ctime(int(self._start)))
current = datetime.strptime(time.ctime(int(self._start)),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
print("current",current)
```

Thank you Alex:

My final code ended up being this.

```
parsed = datetime.strptime(time.ctime(int(self._start)),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
current = parsed.strftime('%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `Wed Jan 14` definitely does **not** "match format" `%m/%d/%Y`!

You **can** parse that string as `'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'`.  For example:

```
>>> thestr = time.ctime()
>>> thestr
'Wed Jan 14 18:53:48 2015'
>>> parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime(thestr, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
>>> parsed
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 14, 18, 53, 48)
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense to me, but then how can i get it into the format that I want. Month, day, year, hours, min, seconds?

Comment: `parsed.strftime('%m, %d, %y, %H, %M, %S')`.  Those commas look totally weird to me, but you **have** just said in this comment (it would be better to express your specification by editing your question, by the way!) that commas are what you want!  Anyway, substitute whatever mix of punctuation you **actually** want, and/or `%b` in lieu of `%m` if you want the three-letter abbreviation of the month name rather than the month number, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method of time formatting instead:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

mo, d, y = now.month, now.day, now.year
h, mi, s = now.hour, now.minute, now.second

print '%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d' % (mo, d, y, h, mi, s)
```

You can change to 12 hour clock with `now.hour % 12` instead of `now.hour`.